# userManager.AddToRoleAsync() - Exception thrown: 'Npgsql.PostgresException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I try to add users to a role with these code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string roleId)
    {
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
        var user_role = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name);
        List<string> ListUser = new List<string>();
        foreach (var _user_ in user_role)
        {
            ListUser.Add(_user_.UserName);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < UserList_new.Count; i++)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(UserList_new[i].UserId);
            Debug.WriteLine(user.UserName);
            Debug.WriteLine(user.Email);
            Debug.WriteLine(user.Id);
            IdentityResult result = null;
            if (UserList_new[i].IsSelected && !ListUser.Contains(user.UserName))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Add " + user.UserName);
                **result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);**
            }
            else if (!(UserList_new[i].IsSelected) && ListUser.Contains(user.UserName))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Remove " + user.UserName);
                **result =await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);**
            }
```

But when it get in these below lines, it return error: Exception thrown: 'Npgsql.PostgresException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

```
result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
result =await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
```

I'm using .Net core 3.1 and razor page.
THanks

Comment: Provide exception details. There are no even exception message, only it's type

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk It just showed like that on the Debug console

Comment: There are 2 awaits in series, in a loop, have you tried to do FindByIdAsync(UserList_new[i].UserId) without the await ? Have you tested your code without any await ? Have you tested it with only ONE user in the list ? Above code will hit FindByIdAsync() from multiple threads..

Comment: @Goodies just tried it without await, same error, nothing changed.

Comment: I used try-catch to catch the e.message, and it return this message:"42703: column a.VmsUserId does not exist"
@RomanKalinchuk